# Naming dispatch_queue's in NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

In my app I use NSOperations and NSOperationQueue a lot. When I use regular dispatch_queue_t I get to name them at instantiation time, so they show up in Xcode's Debug Navigator with that name while debugging. Is there any way I can ask NSOperationQueue to name its underlying queues so that I more easily can identify those queues while debugging?